# express left adjoint as a limit

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, adjoint-functors

in MacLane's CWM, P.234 there is this theorem

> **Theorem.** A functor $G: A \rightarrow X$ has a left adjoint if and only if
>
> 1. $G$ preserves limits.
> 2. for any $x \in X$, $\lim (Q:(x \downarrow G) \rightarrow A)$ exists.
>
> And in this case, the left adjoint of $G$ is given by $Fx := \lim (Q:(x \downarrow G) \rightarrow A)$.

My question is:

If this is true then left adjoint commutes with limits since itself is a limit. But this is weird, coz generally left adjoint only commutes with colimits.

Comment: But only for certain limits of certain shape, not all.

Comment: @Randall I don't get it. I thought (if exists) limits commute with limits. Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we say "limits commute" what we mean is that given index categories $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$ and a bifunctor $D:\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}\to\mathcal{C}$, $\int_{I:\mathcal{I}}\int_{J:\mathcal{J}}D(I^+,J^+)\cong\int_{J:\mathcal{J}}\int_{I:\mathcal{I}}D(I^+,J^+)$ where here I'm using [end](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/end) notation. These particular ends correspond to limits. But think about what is happening in this case. Call the left adjoint $F$. We are saying $FX=\int_{Y:(X\downarrow G)}Q(Y^+)$ where $Q:(X\downarrow G)\to\mathcal{A}$ is the projection from the comma category. Now let's say we wanted to say that $F$ preserves limits. That would mean, for every diagram $D:\mathcal{I}\to\mathcal{X}$, $\int_{I:\mathcal{I}}F(D(I^+))\cong F(\int_{I:\mathcal{I}}D(I^+))$. The left side is then $\int_{I:\mathcal{I}}\int_{Y:(D(I^+)\downarrow G)}Q(Y^+)$ where it doesn't even make sense to commute the ends as that would give you $\int_{Y:(D(I^+)\downarrow G)}\int_{I:\mathcal{I}}Q(Y^+)$ where the $I^+$ is no longer in scope. To put it another way, the "bifunctor" you'd need would need a domain like a dependent sum, $\sum_{I:\mathcal{I}}(D(I)\downarrow G)\to\mathcal{A}$. Meanwhile, the right hand side of the limit preservation isomorphism would look like $\int_{Y:(\int_{I:\mathcal{I}}D(I^+)\downarrow G)}Q(Y^+)$ which doesn't even consist of a composition of limits. So what's happening is that for each $X$, $FX$ is the limit of a *differently shaped* diagram. We can't commute the limit inward in $\int_{I:\mathcal{I}}F(D(I^+))$ because the outer limit is determining the shape of the inner limit.

This result is also in Kelly's book [Basic Concepts of Enriched Category Theory](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10.pdf#page82), Theorem 4.81, where it is expressed as:

> $G$ has a left adjoint if and only if $\text{Ran}_G Id$ exists and is
>   preserved by $G$ in which case the left adjoint is $\text{Ran}_G Id$
>   where $\text{Ran}_G Id$ is the right Kan extension of $Id$ along $G$.

Assuming sufficient completeness of $\mathcal{A}$, we can write $FX\cong\int_{A:\mathcal{\mathcal{A}}}[\mathcal{X}(X,GA^-),A^+]$ where $[S,A]$ is a [power](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/power), i.e. the $S$-indexed coproduct of $A$, $\coprod_{s\in S}A$, and this end is a genuine end and not just a limit (though it can be expressed as a limit which gives rise to Mac Lane's version). Now we can commute the ends in $\int_{I:\mathcal{I}}F(D(I^+))$, but it still doesn't lead to $F(\int_{I:\mathcal{I}}D(I^+)$. The former is $\int_{I:\mathcal{I}}\int_{A:\mathcal{\mathcal{A}}}[\mathcal{X}(D(I^+),GA^-),A^+]\cong\int_{A:\mathcal{\mathcal{A}}}\int_{I:\mathcal{I}}[\mathcal{X}(D(I^+),GA^-),A^+]$, while the latter is $\int_{A:\mathcal{\mathcal{A}}}[\mathcal{X}(\int_{I:\mathcal{I}}D(I^+),GA^-),A^+]$. If these were isomorphic (which they aren't in general), then it certainly doesn't immediately follow *just* from commutation of limits/ends.